# Adding items to a constant list

Tags: java

I want to create an interface for collision detection that contains a list of collidable objects but j know that all members of a interface are constant. How would I go about this. I Cannot substitute this for an abstract class because the class I'm creating already inherents from a parent class.

Comment: Don't use an interface for this as this in no way is what an interface is meant to be used for.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood. The interface would look like this.

Comment: Not your down-voter, and I'm not misunderstanding at all. This is definitely not something that an interface is to be used for.

Comment: Public interface collidable{ void checkCollisions(); List collidableObjects;} and then the class would look like this public class object implements collidable{ @override checkCollisions(){ for (object o : collidableObjects){// do stuff} } } I apologize for the bad format

Comment: That's because code should not be posted in comments. It's too important to be buried in the temporary section of your question. Elevate the code to the question -- but the answer is still the same. And you're mis-using inheritance. You don't want to do this.

Comment: You're putting implementation details in an interface, directly against what they should be used for.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance though I'm still lost on how I'm going to implement this

Comment: That's too broad of a question. At this point about all one can say is: don't use interfaces for this. Re-read what they're used for.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put concrete implementation details within an interface, and to do this is a misuse of inheritance. The correct solution is to simply not do this. Use interfaces for redirection, to loosen coupling, to abstract pure behavior, and to help use design patterns, but not to implement concrete aspects of your program.